# Error selecting hstore column value from source and inserting it into target using Pentaho

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, hstore

I am trying to select a hstore value from source DB and insert into target using ETL in Pentaho. But for some unknown reasons it is converting the hstore value to varchar. I tried casting the datatype to hstore after selecting but still the error persists. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue.

FYI: when I try Execute SQL transformation to insert the hstore value strangely the transformation runs successfully.

Comment: Which database are you using??

Answer (score 0):

This function below creates the CAST in the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_to_hstore(input character varying)
  RETURNS public_extensions.hstore AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN hstore_in(input::cstring);
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

CREATE CAST (character varying AS hstore) WITH FUNCTION text_to_hstore(character varying) as assignment;
```

Once the function is created run the ETL transforamtion/job without casting it. The function will converters the output text value to an hstore value. Hope this helps.